# React access and update variable outside of render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning React and am following this [guy Youtube Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUPWpXsmuaM&index=11&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i0_2FF-WhtRIfIJ1lXlTZR).

However, they are outdated and it's difficult to get along with the old codes. I already tried some Stackoverflow and Google solutions, but they didn't help.

Right now am I struggling on how I can access my variable `todo` which I declared inside `render()` and update it with a my function `handleDelete` outside of `render()`?

My goal is to delete the item i clicked on.

I already tried to set my variable inside constructor() but then it wasn't possible to give it the value of this.props.todos.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {

  handleDelete(item){
    let updatedTodos = this.props.todos;
    updatedTodos = updatedTodos.filter((val,index) => {
      return item !== val;
    })
    todos = updatedTodos;
  };

  render() {
    //Add all this.props items
    let todos = this.props.todos;
    todos = todos.map((item, index) => {

      return (
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{item}</span>
          <span className="item-remove" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, item)}> x </span>
        </div>
      </li>);
    });


    return (<React.Fragment>{todos}</React.Fragment>)
  };
}
```

(This code is later exported to index.js where it is transpiled with Babel)

Thanks for your time taken!

**Update:**

Here is `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import TodoItem from './todoItem'; 

class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        todos: ["clean up", "walk doggo", "take nap"]
      };
    }
    render() {

      return (<div>

        <h1>The todo list:</h1>
        <ul>
          <TodoItem todos={this.state.todos}/>
        </ul>
      </div>);
    }

  }

  ReactDom.render(<TodoComponent/>, document.querySelector(".todo-wrapper"));
```

Comment: You are getting `todos` as a prop so it should be in a parent component's state. Like `todos` you need a `delete` handler from your parent component as a prop. Then you will use this function in your `handleDelete` function and pass the `todos`. Can we see your parent component as well?

Comment: your second return statment would never fire

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, second `return` belongs to `render`. First one is for `map`. So, actually it should work.

Comment: Ah.. what is an item?? an object or string or number

Comment: Those are the missing parts since OP does not show rest of the code. This is why I want to see the parent component. But, I am guessing it is just a string for now.

Comment: See as per you code formation, even if everything is working fine your component will not re render itself. Because there is no state change

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, you know I'm not the OP :) In the first comment I tried to explain this. There must be another prop for handling state change in the parent component.

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala I added index.js file :) Thanks for trying to help out!

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I suggest that you learn about variable scope in JavaScript. Also learn about state management in ReactJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TodoComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import TodoItem from './todoItem'; 

class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        todos: ["clean up", "walk doggo", "take nap"]
      };
    }
    handleDelete(item){
        let todos = this.state.todos;
        todos= todos.filter((todo) => todo !== item);
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            todos: todos
        }));
    };
    render() {

      return (<div>

        <h1>The todo list:</h1>
        <ul>
          <TodoItem todos={this.state.todos} handleDelete={this.handleDelete}/>
        </ul>
      </div>);
    }

  }

  ReactDom.render(<TodoComponent/>, document.querySelector(".todo-wrapper"));
```

Todo Item

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            this.props.todos.map((item) => {
            return (
                <li>
                    <div className="todo-item">
                    <span className="item-name">{item}</span>
                    <span className="item-remove" onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(item)}> x </span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            )
        }))
    }
}
```

Your code is having the problem in `TodoItem` that you are trying to delete items in `TodoItem` where you do not have access to state. And moreover If you do some actions in component and you want to get the change reflected the your components must re render. And this is possible when your state is changed. And component related to corresponding changes will re render itself

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to even rebuild my code into a more proper and professional one, I love to learn but I even more love it to analyse!
p.s. Would it not be better to use let todos instead of const? Since we're updating the array

Comment: You can update the variables created as `const`, you only can not reassign them.

Comment: There is a single difference between const and let. let allows you to reassign the variable but const doesnot  allows to do that

Comment: There are two problems with this code. I said only updating `const` is OK but here @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala is reassigning it. This does not work. Here is the right way: `const todos = this.state.todos;
    const newTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo !== item);
    this.setState({
      todos: newTodos,
    });`

Comment: Aftet that a second problem will rise. This `handleDelete` is not bind to `this`. Either bind it or use an arrow function. Hence, here is the right function: `handleDelete = (item) => {
    const todos = this.state.todos;
    const newTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo !== item);
    this.setState({
      todos: newTodos,
    });
  };`

Comment: change const to let

Comment: arrow function doesnot have reference to this by default. Even if someone finds issue with that please try binding 'this' in contructor

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, this is why arrow function works here. No need to use and bind the regular function. Also, I strongly suggest avoiding directly assigning the state to a variable and change it. At least change it like `let todos = [ ...this.state.todos ];`

Comment: Does that mean if I change todos will change the state?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, not this situation since you are filtering it and it returns a new array again. But still it is not suggested to use directly like this. Just run those examples: `const todos = [ "foo" , "bar", "baz" ];
const newTodos = todos;

newTodos.splice(0, 1);

console.log(todos);
console.log(newTodos);` and `const someObj = {
  name: "foo",
  age: 25,
  location: "some place"
};

const newObj = someObj;

newObj.name = "bar";

console.log(someObj);
console.log(newObj);`

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it so there might be some typos but you have to do it like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {

handleDelete(item){
   this.props.updateTodos(item)
};

render() {
//Add all this.props items
 let todos = this.props.todos;
 todos = todos.map((item, index) => {

  return (
  <li>
    <div className="todo-item">
      <span className="item-name">{item}</span>
      <span className="item-remove" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, item)}> x </span>
    </div>
  </li>);
 });


 return (<React.Fragment>{todos}</React.Fragment>)
};
}



import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import TodoItem from './todoItem'; 

class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    todos: ["clean up", "walk doggo", "take nap"]
  };
  this.updateTodos =this.updateTodos.bind(this);
}
 updateTodos(item){
   this.setState({todos :this.state.todos.filter((val,index) => {
     return item !== val;
   })})
}
render() {

  return (<div>

    <h1>The todo list:</h1>
    <ul>
      <TodoItem todos={this.state.todos} updateTodos ={this.updateTodos}/>
    </ul>
  </div>);
}

}

 ReactDom.render(<TodoComponent/>, document.querySelector(".todo-wrapper"));
```

Comment: can you try now. I used a wrong variable there. share the error message if any

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting a different approach for you. There are some issues you need to think better. First of all, I suggest keeping your `todo`s as objects and let have them `id` and `text` properties.

Second, you have a separate component but you are passing to it whole `todos`. Instead of that, map your `todos` and then pass each `todo` to your component. In this way your management over everything will be easier.

For your situation, you need a delete handler to pass your `TodoItem`, then by using this handler you will do the action.

Lastly, your `TodoItem` does not need to be a class component, so I've changed it.

Here is a working example. I've changed your code according to my suggestions.

```js
class Todos extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: "foo" },
      { id: 2, text: "bar" },
      { id: 3, text: "baz" },
    ]
  }

  deleteTodo = ( todo ) => {
    const newTodos = this.state.todos.filter( el => el.id !== todo.id );
    this.setState({ todos: newTodos });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {
          todos.map( todo => <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo} /> )
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const TodoItem = props => {
  const handleDelete = () => props.deleteTodo(props.todo);

  return (
    <li onClick={handleDelete}>{props.todo.text} x</li>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<Todos />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also, last night I wrote a small example for another question. But it got bigger and bigger and I did not post it. But here is a small, simple Todo example. Of course there must be some improvements but you can examine it as an example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/01v3kmp9vv

**Edit**

If you don't want to use `class-fields` and install another Babel plugin, just change the related part with this:

```
class Todos extends React.Component {
  consturctor( props ) {
      super( props );
      this.state = {
          todos: [
          { id: 1, text: "foo" },
          { id: 2, text: "bar" },
          { id: 3, text: "baz" },
        ],
  }
}
....rest of the code
```

Comment: I know it works and I can write like that. But there are some problems with this approach. Only keeping text values is not for me, I rather keeping my todos here as an object. Second problem passing all the `todos` state to Child component and map there. This is not necessary, `TodoItem` component does some actions with a single `todo`, so it should get a single `todo`. This is why I am mapping `todos` in the  passing a single `todo` to it. Also, in OP's and your version `Todo` item binds a function for `onClick` and this function recreated in each render.

Comment: Very nice work and explanation! Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as a solution but your's is also very much appreciated!!

Comment: @MaxFrenter no problem about accepting my answer. But I strongly advice you to look the official documentation first: https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html Learning something with the right way is very important. Before going any further just learn the basic concepts. Then you will see how clear is everything.

Comment: Ill do that! Unfortunately I just tried your code with mine and I got also an error: https://imgur.com/a/kXDuVeH

Comment: I'm using class-fields here. Babel needs a plugin for that: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/  With Create React App all those good stuff comes preinstalled and preconfigured :)

Comment: I've tried CRA before, but I also tried to find a doc about how CRA transpiles its files and what the default settings are... - couldn't find them :/

Comment: CRA configuration? Create a test project with it and just do: `yarn eject` and look the configuration files. When I started to learn React I wanted to focus only it, so I skipped Webpack and all the other configuration part. Some people prefers learning Webpack and others, I prefer saving time. As you can see my code actually works, just run the snippet :)

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an alternative code without `class-fields`.